# Dealing with commas in CSV

Tags: php, javascript, regex, soap, csv

I get a CSV data from a SOAP call in php. Unfortunately, the data may have commas in it. It is formatted correctly as in

1,name,2,lariat,3,"first, last",5,NMEA,...

I need to parse it to individual values in either php or javascript. I have browsed through threads on stack overflow and elsewhere but have not found a specific solution in php / javascript.

The approach I am currently using is

```
$subject = '123,name,456,lryyrt,123213,"first,last",8585,namea3';
$pattern = '/,|,"/';
$t2=preg_replace ('/,|(".*")/','$0*',$subject);
$t2=str_replace(',','*',$t2);
$t2=str_replace('*',',',$t2);
```

Where * is the deliminator, but the `preg_replace` generates an extra *. I have tried a couple of other approaches involving `preg_match` and other `preg_` functions but did not succeed in having any kind of a clean split.

Any suggestion on how to split up CSV data that contains commas in it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Don't attempt to do this with a regular expression.  Just use [`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/function.str-getcsv.php)!  The third parameter informs `str_getcsv()` to look for quote-enclosed fields.

```
$subject = '123,name,456,lryyrt,123213,"first,last",8585,namea3';
$array = str_getcsv($subject, ",", '"');

print_r($array);
// Prints:
Array
(
    [0] => 123
    [1] => name
    [2] => 456
    [3] => lryyrt
    [4] => 123213
    [5] => first,last
    [6] => 8585
    [7] => namea3
)
```

Comment: To note, str_getcsv isn't available until PHP 5.3. Prior to that fgetcsv was used. If you weren't getting your content directly from a file or other stream then you might have to force it into a stream (php://memory, write then position reset) or file first.

Answer (score 1):

Just another way to convert a csv file to an associative array.

```
<?php
//
// Convert csv file to associative array:
//

function csv_to_array($input, $delimiter=',')
{
    $header = null;
    $data = array();
    $csvData = str_getcsv($input, "\n");

    foreach($csvData as $csvLine){
        if(is_null($header)) $header = explode($delimiter, $csvLine);
        else{

            $items = explode($delimiter, $csvLine);

            for($n = 0, $m = count($header); $n < $m; $n++){
                $prepareData[$header[$n]] = $items[$n];
            }

            $data[] = $prepareData;
        }
    }

    return $data;
}

//-----------------------------------
//
//Usage:

$csvArr = csv_to_array(file_get_contents('test.csv'));

?>
```

Comment: @Phoenix - What part of this deals with commas in the data and quotations? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

**For JavaScript use [jQuery-CSV](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-csv/)**

If you're already using jQuery, just add the jquery-csv.js module to expose the extension methods. Then just convert the CSV directly to a JavaScript array.

**If you're only parsing the following will convert it to a one-dimensional array:**

```
$.csv.toArray(csv);
```

**If you have a multi-line CSV string the following will convert it to a two-dimensional array:**

```
$.csv.toArrays(csv);
```

*Note: all the different line endings are detected and split correctly using a smart regex.*

The default delimiter is a double-quote (") and the default separator is a comma (,) but you can change use custom settings by specifying them in the method call.

**Ex:**

$.csv.toArray(csv, {
     separator:';',
     delimiter:"'"
   });

I created the project to provide an end-to-end CSV parser written in JavaScript that takes the guesswork out of importing-exporting CSV.

Doing the heavy lifting on the client removes unnecessary load on the server and removes any unnecessary AJAX round-trips to the server.

**Update:**

**If you're looking for a server-side solution, the library also works on Node.js.**

Comment: Thank you. I think I'll choose something like this for a client side csv processing, but my application was based on the server side and I had to query some non-relational database that gave csv outputs.

Comment: I am sorry. I think I had forgotten the question :-(. I had after all posted it nearly an year ago and that project has been closed. Thank you for pointing out the jQuery alternative. I shall remain in the corner of my mind, should I need it again :-)

Comment: @LordLoh. If you need a server-side solution, I just confirmed that the plugin works with Node.js too. The details on how to import into a Node.js script can be found on the project page.