# How to import the column value as comma from mysql data to csv file using php

Tags: php, mysql, csv

In csv file i need a comma in column value.

Here is the mysql query:

```
$q_pack = "select p.filename, p.version, dt.name as external,p.internal
          from cert c 
            join packages p on c.package_id=p.id 
            left join documents dt on p.id=dt.package_id 
            left join documents doc on doc.id=d.document_id 
          where c.certificate_id=100";

$res_pack = db_query($q_pack);
if ($res_pack){
$fp = fopen('sample.csv', 'w');
$title = "filename, version, external,internal";
fwrite($fp, $title);
while ($pack_row = db_fetch_object($res_pack)){
fwrite($fp, "\n");
foreach ( $pack_row as $line ) {
$val = $line.',';
fwrite($fp, $val);}}
fclose($fp);}
```

Here column name as "external" and the value is joe,bob. In mysql table the value of external return as joe,bob, but in csv file it displayed as joe is in one column and bob is in another column.

Please refer the screenshot for CSV file.
[Csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaioL.jpg)

Comment: need to escape the column headers

Comment: @clearshot66 can you please explain it briefly

Comment: `fputcsv($fp, array('Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3', 'Column 4', 'Column 5'));` wouldn't this work?

Comment: You should enclose it. The default enclosure is double quotes. In this way you can parse it back using `str_getcsv` http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php And see related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536826/dealing-with-commas-in-csv

Comment: @PrashanthBenny I'm using the mysql query, then where should i mention fputcsv

Comment: @DanMiller i already tried the code like this $val = str_getcsv($line.",".'"'); , but it showing the empty file only the title.

Comment: You have 3 columns returned from your query and you have output 4 column headings in your CSV file???

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry i removed one column in query. now i updated the query

Comment: Argh. Find a CSV library and use it. Don't try to roll your own. It isn't worth the effort.

Comment: It's like, retrieve the data from database using the MySQL query, Make each row, from the data that you have got, into an array. And write each array to the file, using fputcsv. Am I making it understandable now?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `fputcsv()` it will automatically enclosure your fields with commas in double quotes

```
$res_pack = db_query($q_pack);
$fp = fopen('sample.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($fp, ['filename', 'version', 'external', 'internal']);
while ($pack_row = db_fetch_array($res_pack)) {
    fputcsv($fp, $pack_row);
}
fclose($fp);
```

So in this case, sample row:

```
array(
    'filename' => 'file',
    'version' => 10
    'external' => 'foo,bar'
    'internal' => 'baz'
);
```

will be encoded as follows `file,10,"foo,bar",baz`

Read more: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php